# wait until images in background (css) are loaded

Tags: jquery, css, background

Let's say we have a slideshow of pictures. the thumbnails of those pictures are showed in div wrapper with a slider (that I created with Jquery) and each image is included in a `<li>` with a CSS background set, which of course represents the image. I chose to use a background-image for a layout matter because they all are different in size and aspect ratio.

The images comes from a db and are dynamically created.

**What I wanna do is:**

show a "loading" message over every `<li>` and wait until the background(image) is loaded in the cache and then show it with a fadeIn.
They only way I can think of (not that I can since I'm not very sure how and if its doable) is:

- temporally unset the background for every `<li>` while showing the "loading" message
- make a loop for every background to get the image url
- use the $.get function to load it and then do whatever I want after loading

Beside the doable thing, this would imply they would load in sequence so if one won't load for some reason the script will never continue!

I've seen some sites that use JS to load images only when its visible by the browser, maybe this could be the same case I'm looking for, since I'm using a scroller and only a part of the images are showed at once and when the page loads

Comment: have you thought about using a sprite?, so you only have to load 1 image into the DOM and then every image is sliced from that, will make life simpler, just load the css sheet onload event for sprite image, and then just show loader for all elements until the CSS sheet is loaded.

Comment: not possible, the images comes from a DB

Answer (score 8):

Well, I think things may be simpler if you just use `img` tags, but if you do want to use background images then I could only come up with a work around.

The trick is to create a new image (using [**the Javascript image object**](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/image.shtml)), and make sure it's loaded, but this image isn't displayed. Once the image is loaded and in the cache, that image will be available as a background image in your gallery.

So, all you have to do is make sure that you only change the background image of the `LI` of an image after the corresponding image is loaded. You can load all `LI`s with a default "loading" image initially.

So your code would be something like:

HTML (the `style` definitions for the loading image could be in your external style sheet):

```
<ul>
<li id="pic1" style="background-image:url('images/loading.gif')"></li>
<li id="pic2" style="background-image:url('images/loading.gif')"></li>
<li id="pic3" style="background-image:url('images/loading.gif')"></li>
...
</ul>
```

Your jQuery / Javascript:

```
var img = new Array();

// The following would be in some sort of loop or array iterator:

var num = [NUMBER] // You'd use this number to keep track of multiple images.
  // You could also do this by using $("ul>li").each() and using the index #

img[num] = new Image();

  // Specify the source for the image
var imgSource = "http://yourimage.com/example.jpg";

  // only append the corresponding LI after the image is loaded
img[num].onload = function() {
    $("#pic" + num).attr("style", "background-image:url('" + imgSource + "')");
};

img[num].src = imgSource;​
```

You would have to have the appropriate CSS / ids etc for each `LI`, and you would have to adapt the above to the loop or function you use to show your gallery.

[**Here's a jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/C4uYn/). (for testing purposes it's a big image, so it takes a while to load).

Comment: I think I got what you're saying. 
The problem is that my images are set as background in the in-style code like this

<li style="background: url('/media/images_thumb/daniel/6.jpg') center  no-repeat"></li>

So I'll need to all the images first for every li and then make them objects? can I get the backgrounds in Jquery?

Comment: @Sandro - That's okay, just use a variable to set the image source and bg image for each LI. Something like this ==> http://jsfiddle.net/aDDkZ/ - edited answer to reflect changes

Comment: Hi, I think I got how to get the css value from li to know the img url, BUT wouldn't this imply that I have to wait either for ALL the images to load or for every image in sequence only? I'd like to show single images, independently,  whenever they're loaded.

Comment: @Sandro - No, but you'd have to use an arry or multiple img variables. I changed the code a little to show how you could handle many images

Answer (score 2):

You can you a css trick instead of some long javascript code.
Here you can do it like this:

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="slideshow-container">
  <li><div id="image1"></div></li>
  <li><div id="image2"></div></li>
  <li><div id="image3"></div></li>
  <li><div id="image4"></div></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
#slideshow-container>li{
  background-image:url('loading.gif')
}

#slideshow-container>li>div{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

#slideshow-container>li>div{
  background-color:transparent;
}

#image1{
  background-image:url('image1.jpg');
}

#image2{
  background-image:url('image2.jpg');
}

#image3{
  background-image:url('image3.jpg');
}

#image4{
  background-image:url('image4.jpg');
}
```

**Explanation:**
The Images of the slideshow will be the background of div contained in the li.
Until the images are loaded the background will be transparent, which will show the background of the li which is the animated loading gif.
In simple terms loading image of li will be shown until slideshow image contained in the div is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

well, i think that maybe you are making things too complicated. I'm not really sure why you're using css background when the images could be inside a  tag. You say the reason is because your images are dynamically created... and i dont understand that.

What you could do is create a page that returns the images, maybe you could use some parameter... something like the image size:

```
http://www.mysite.com/create_image.php?size=200x100&id=img1
```

then all you need to do is put this url inside the SRC of the img tag... If you want to, you could pre-load the image when the page is loaded..or when your slider is moving

Or maybe i didn't understood your problem =D

Comment: read the post :P
"because they all are different in size and aspect ratio."

it would be a mess, there are images like 100x800px so using a background does crop them yes but also gives a fixed size

Comment: yeah i read that part... that's why you can pass the size as a parameter, look at this.. i made this for a website 

http://jleanoma.perso.info.unicaen.fr/feed-bee/helpers/images.php?size=large&urlImage=http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif

you can change the urlImage and you can also specify the size (small or large). Inside the code, i dinamically resize the image always keeping the aspect ratio and the result is allways the same size.
You put that url into a img tag and you're done..

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use from this is have two layers of elements.

One layer is a case that has the background loading symbol as the background. This is always seen. Then in a second layer above, I place the element with the images and use a jQuery `.ready()` function with a `.delay()` and `.fade()`.

Because this is convoluted to explain, I'll show what I do:

```
    <!-- Page Elements -->

    <div id="background-loading"> // Background image of spinner
      <div id="slider-case"> // Container of slider
        <ul id="slider-content">
          <li class="slider-image"></li>
          <li class="slider-image"></li>
          <li class="slider-image"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Script -->

  // Somewhere you have a script that manages the slider
  // Below is the loading animation/image manager
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slider-content').delay(200).animate({opacity:1.0}, 'linear', function(){ 
      $('#background-loading').animate({opacity:0, 'margin-left':'-70px'}, 'linear');
      $('.slider-image').animate({opacity:1.0, 'margin-left':'0em'}, 'linear', function(){});
    });
  });
```

The delay and fade makes the loading time seem intentional, while the `.ready()` will wait until the element is completely loaded.

By having a separate background layer, you don't have to worry about manipulating anything in addition to the slider. To add an additional effect, you can make a callback to the image load that does a fade to the loading animation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks for elements with src attribute or backgroundImage css property and calls an action function when theirs images loaded.

```
/**
 * Load and wait for loading images.
 */
function loadImages(images, action){
    var loaded_images = 0;
    var bad_tags = 0;        

    $(images).each(function() {
    //alert($(this).get(0).tagName+" "+$(this).attr("id")+" "+$(this).css("display"));
        var image = new Image();
        var src = $(this).attr("src");
        var backgroundImage = $(this).css("backgroundImage");            
        // Search for css background style
        if(src == undefined && backgroundImage != "none"){
            var pattern = /url\("{0,1}([^"]*)"{0,1}\)/;                
            src = pattern.exec(backgroundImage)[1];                
        }else{
            bad_tags++;
        }
        // Load images
        $(image).load(function() {
            loaded_images++;                
            if(loaded_images == ($(images).length - bad_tags))
                action();
        })
        .attr("src", src);
    });
}
```