# Animate opacity on image load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have tried a bunch of different solutions to similar problems on here but none of them seem to be doing anything for me. See my jsFiddle to see an example of what I would like to happen: http://jsfiddle.net/Amp3rsand/HSNY5/6/

It animates how I would like but it relies on .delay when I would prefer it to fire as soon as the image is finished loading. The commented out sections in the js are the things that I have tried.

Could the problem be that the image is actually the background of a div rather than its own element? I tested making it its own `<img>` tag as well but it didn't seem to make a difference. I have the image as the background so that when I use media queries it is easy to swap in a different, smaller image for mobile users or small screens.

HTML:

```
<header></header>
<div id="image">
    <div id="blah"></div>
</div>
```

The image I would like to fire after it finishes loading is the background of '#image'. Then I would like for it to animate to 'opacity:1;' while '#blah' and 'header' are animated into place.

Here is the jQuery I'm using right now but it is not correct:

```
$('#image').hide().delay(800).fadeTo(600, 1);
$('#blah').css("left", "-650px").delay(1400).animate({left:'30px'},400);
$('header').css("top", "-150px").delay(2000).animate({top:'-5px'},400);
```

On my website it is quite a large image so it takes about half a second to load but this code doesn't take into account caching or different network speeds.

What am I doing wrong or what should I do differently?

Thanks everyone

---

EDIT:

I gave the imagesLoaded plugin a go earlier and it seems to work on my website but I can't tell if it is actually doing what I want or just emulating my code from above.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').hide().fadeTo(500, 1)
});
imagesLoaded( document.querySelector('#homeimg'), function( instance ) {
  $('article').hide().fadeTo(600, 1);
  $('#caption').css("left", "-650px").delay(800).animate({left:'30px'},400);
$('header').css("top", "-150px").delay(1400).animate({top:'-5px'},400);
});
```

'#homeimg' being the div with the image as the background and 'article' being the container for '#homeimg' and '#caption'

I can only test with the website loaded locally at the moment so I can't simulate a slow connection. Does the code above do what I am looking for? Sorry if it should be obvious

Comment: https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

Comment: I have seen this as a solution for a bunch of other questions so I put together a version that works but I can't tell if it is doing what I really want. See my edit if you want to see what I mean

Answer (score 1):

Your image is loaded via a CSS background property, you will not be able to detect the loading of that. Why not use `<img>` tag for images?

If you use `<img>` you can read this question: [Browser-independent way to detect when image has been loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821516/browser-independent-way-to-detect-when-image-has-been-loaded) for a bullet-proof solution.

If you insist on using a `background` CSS property you will need to implement a way of sending your image as a data url encoded as base64 as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13989806/2788

Comment: That makes sense and I sort of figured it was the case. I wasn't using an img tag because I wanted to be able to swap in a different size for mobile users or people with small screens using media queries.

Comment: How does using something like this from your first link look?http://jsfiddle.net/Amp3rsand/6xDus/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try animate

```
$('#image').animate({ opacity: '1'}, 600);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the initial opacity to 0, and when the image `onload`ed, set the opacity to 1. With CSS you can make a transition between the two states:

```html
<style>
.easeload{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease; 
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease; 
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease; 
    -o-transition: all 2s ease; 
}
</style>

<img class="easeload" onload="this.style.opacity=1" src="https://dummyimage.com/320x240">
```