# Do an jquery/javascript action after loading set of CSS background images

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, background

I encountered a problem that I really don't know how to solve it.

I created a slideshow, like the following image

[image]

This slideshow contains 7 pieces, when it is loaded every piece of the image is displayed one after another (with 700 milliseconds time delay) and after completion another image is displayed in the same way.

There is only one image for every the set of pieces, I mean I didn't cut the image into pieces, It is one image and a layer of `Div`s are displaying different pieces of the image. This is my code :

Every one of the following `DIV`s contains one piece of the image

```
<div class='slider-container'>
    <div class="slider-section slider-section1"></div>
    <div class="slider-section slider-section2"></div>
    <div class="slider-section slider-section3"></div>
    <div class="slider-section slider-section4"></div>
    <div class="slider-section slider-section5"></div>
    <div class="slider-section slider-section6"></div>
</div>
```

and it is CSS of two `DIV`s

```
.slider-container > div{
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow : 2px 3px 21px #303030;
    display: none;
}
.slider-section1{
    background:  repeat scroll -32px -42px / 470px 360px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 138px;
    width: 188px;
    left:32px;
    top : 42px;
}
.slider-section2{
    background: repeat scroll -222px -2px / 470px 360px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 178px;
    width: 80px;
    left:222px;
    top : 2px;
}
.
.
.
```

And now by setting background image to `.slider-container > div` I can set image for all of the `DIV`s and each one will display some section of it.

The problem is with **delay** in loading the background images. Because the background images are changed by Javascript (the url of background images are stored in an array in Javsscript), some times the loading the images takes a few seconds and it causes an empty section like this

[image]

it is not good to display empty set of sections then waiting for caching the images by browser in the next times. It also happens when slideshow is loaded for the first time.

**How can I solve this problem?**

Is there anyway to load the `slider-container` only when all of the background images are loaded? or any other way to prevent empty section?

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE:**

This is javascript (The url of background images are stored in `.preload-image span.field-content` element)

```
(function($)
{
    var imageArray= [];
    var rate = 700;
    var imagePointer=0;
    var imageCounter=0;
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        function slider(){
            var time=300;
            $(".slider-container > div").css("background-image","url('"+imageArray[imagePointer]+"')");
            imagePointer++;
            if(imageCounter == imagePointer)
                imagePointer=0;
            setTimeout(
                    function() 
                     {
                         $(".slider-section1").fadeIn(time);
                     }, rate);
                setTimeout(
                        function() 
                        {
                            $(".slider-section2").fadeIn(time);
                        }, rate * 2);
                setTimeout(
                        function() 
                        {
                            $(".slider-section3").fadeIn(time);
                        }, rate * 3);
                setTimeout(
                        function() 
                        {
                            $(".slider-section4").fadeIn(time);
                        }, rate * 4);
                setTimeout(
                        function() 
                        {
                            $(".slider-section5").fadeIn(time);
                        }, rate * 5);
                setTimeout(
                        function() 
                        {
                            $(".slider-section6").fadeIn(time);
                        }, rate * 6);
                setTimeout(
                        function() 
                        {
                            $(".slider-section7").fadeIn(time);
                        }, rate * 7);
                setTimeout(
                        function() 
                        {
                            $(".slider-container > div").fadeOut(time);
                        }, rate * 12);
        }
        $(".preload-image span.field-content").each(function() {
               var src = $(this).text();
               imageArray[imageCounter++] = src;
        });
        slider();
        setInterval(function() {
            slider();
        },rate * 12.5);
    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

The `imageArray` array contains set of urls and `imagePointer` points to the current image.

I also tried `$(window).load(function()` or `$(document).load(function()` functions but since the background images are loaded by some JavaScript code and not at the beginning of the page load, so this way seems to be useless.

Comment: how are you loading the images? i.e. how are you changing them in JavaScript? **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3492277/3344111)** might help.

Comment: @TahirAhmed I updated the question and included the changing image code

Comment: @TahirAhmed thanks, I will work on it

Answer (score 0):

You can preload all the images just by using this :

```
$.preloadImages = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    $("<img />").attr("src", arguments[i]);
  }
}

$.preloadImages("image1.jpg","image2.jpg");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.There are two problems, `$(window).load(function()` is not fired and the second one is that the background images are not loaded at first by loading the page, they are loaded by a javascript code So `load` function makes no sense here

Comment: so you need to load one script after another ? is that what you intended ?

Comment: No, there is no problem with script the problem is loading the background images. After completion an image, loading the next image takes a few seconds and it causes empty section

Comment: you can use preloading element in javascript which can preload the next image while processing the current one .. this can work for you

Comment: that's good idea cause completing the current image takes 13 seconds but  How can I do that?

Comment: changed the answer, you can use it to preload the images as per your need .. in preloadImages you can use any array or pointer to call the images stack

Comment: what is `$.preloadImages("image1.jpg","image2.jpg");`? and how can I use these in setting as background ?

Comment: those are the images to be preloaded, one after another .. just use it before the if loop in your javascript